# Is seekg or ignore more efficient?

Tags: c++, performance

I'm using C++ to write a very time-sensitive application, so efficiency is of the utmost importance.

I have a `std::ifstream`, and I want to jump a specific amount of characters (a.k.a. byte offset, I'm not using `wchar_t`) to get to a specific line instead of using `std::getline` to read every single line because it is too inefficient for me.

Is it better to use `seekg` or `ignore` to skip a specified number of characters and start reading from there?

```
size_t n = 100;
std::ifstream f("test");
f.seekg(n, std::ios_base::beg);
// vs.
f.ignore(n);
```

Comment: *so efficiency is of the utmost importance.* -- Why not do your own tests instead of trusting what an anonymous poster tells you?   It's your application, thus you should be able to determine this yourself by proper testing.  Once you run the tests, and you have further questions about how /  what you tested, then that would make much more sense to start asking a few questions as to the results and if something can be done differently (if the results are too slow).

Comment: `seekg` takes a [`std::ios_base::seekdir`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/seekdir) as its second parameter by the way.

Comment: Define "very time-sensitive". That goal sounds contrary to seeking around in text files.

Comment: Caution: `std::getline` and `ignore` understand line endings; `seekg` does not. On Windows, the line ending in a text file is two characters long; on other systems it's one. So the number of **bytes** that you have to skip can be different, depending on the system that wrote the file. `std::getline` and `ignore` will handle that; `seekg` may need to have the number of bytes adjusted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at cplusplus.com for both functions, it seems like `ignore` will use sbumpc or sgetc to skip the requested amount of characters. This means that it works even on streams that do not natively support skipping (which ifstream does), but it also processes every single byte.

`seekg` on the other hand uses pubseekpos or pubseekoff, which is implementation defined. For files, this should directly skip to the desired position without processing the bytes up to it.

I would expect `seekg` to be much more efficent, but as others said: doing your own tests with a big file would be the best way to go for you.